# Помогите реализовать шифре виженера на python

Tags: python-3.x, шифрование

Нужна помощь с реализацией 2-х функций для шифрования и расшифрования русского текста при помощи шифра Виженера. Важно чтобы при шифровке сохранялись знаки препинания, пробелы между словами.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.